# Python script has function that have repetitive code

Tags: python-3.x

I have this piece of code in Python where functions are being used with a lot of the code lines doing the same thing. The only difference is the endpoint name differs from the rest. The endpoint are being called from a separate Flask app.

```
def add_latency(mbxIP, latency):
         url = f"http://{mbxIP}:5000/add_latency?ms={latency}"
         response = requests.get(url)
         if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                print('OK')
                return True
         else:
                print(f"ERROR in add_latency. URL: {url}. Response code: {response.status_code}")
         return False

 def remove_latency(mbxIP, latency):
         url = f"http://{mbxIP}:5000/remove_latency?ms={latency}";response = requests.get(url)
         if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                print('OK')
                return True
         else:
                print(f"ERROR in remove_latency. URL: {url}. Response code: {response.status_code}")
         return False

 def add_jitter(mbxIP, jitter):
         url = f"http://{mbxIP}:5000/add_jitter?ms={jitter}"
         response = requests.get(url)
         if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                print('OK')
                return True
         else:
                print(f"ERROR in add_jitter. URL: {url}. Response code: {response.status_code}")
         return False

 def remove_jitter(mbxIP, jitter):
         url = f"http://{mbxIP}:5000/remove_jitter?ms={jitter}"
         response = requests.get(url)
         if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                print('OK')
                return True
         else:
                print(f"ERROR in add_jitter. URL: {url}. Response code: {response.status_code}")
         return False
```

How can I reuse the code from one function and prevent repetition?

Comment: Sure, thats the idea of functions. Create a functional that does that and call it inside the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following :

```
def url(a,b,function_name):
    url = f"http://{a}:5000/{function_name}?ms={b}"
    return url

def main_func(url,function_name):
         response = requests.get(url)
         if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                print('OK')
                return True
         else:
                print(f"ERROR in {function_name}. URL: {url}. Response code: {response.status_code}")
         return False

def add_latency(mbxIP, latency):
    return main_func(url(mbxIP,latency),'add_latency')

def remove_latency(mbxIP, latency):
    return main_func(url(mbxIP,latency),'remove_latency')

def add_jitter(mbxIP, jitter):
     return main_func(url(mbxIP,jitter),'add_jitter')

def remove_jitter(mbxIP, jitter):
     return main_func(url(mbxIP,jitter),'remove_jitter')
```

Comment: It is not working as I get an error:
File "./managerInterface.py", line 64, in remove_latency
    return main_func(url(mbxip, latency),'remove_latency')
TypeError: url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function_name'

Comment: Okay thanks I found the issue and resolve it. It should have been return main_func(url(mbxIP,latency, 'remove_latency'),'remove_latency')

Comment: It's my pleasure .